# What part of this UserChrome.css file's meaning has changed in Firefox 113?

Tags: css, firefox, userchrome.css

My UserChrome.css file is as follows:

```css
/*@namespace url("http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul");*/
@namespace xul "http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul";
@namespace html "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml";
.bookmark-item{
    margin-left: 0 !important;
    margin-right: 0 !important;
    padding-right: 0 !important;
    padding-left: 0 !important; 
}
toolbarbutton.bookmark-item .toolbarbutton-text{
    display: none !important;
}
toolbarbutton.bookmark-item .toolbarbutton-icon{
    margin-left: 2px !important;
}
#PlacesToolbarItems > .bookmark-item > .toolbarbutton-icon[label]:not([label=""]) {
    margin-inline-end: 2px !important;
}
toolbarbutton.subviewbutton.subviewbutton-iconic .toolbarbutton-text{
    display: -moz-box !important;
}
/* --- [1] --- */
toolbarbutton.bookmark-item:hover:not(.subviewbutton):not([disabled="true"]):not([open]) .toolbarbutton-text{
    display: -moz-box !important;
}
```

As of Firefox 113, I can no longer see the title of a bookmark when I hover over it in my bookmark toolbar. [I am not alone in this](https://old.reddit.com/r/FirefoxCSS/comments/12nn5lp/how_to_get_roomy_bookmarks_in_ff_112/). Has there been a recent change to Firefox or to CSS that has changed the meaning of the above text?

Comment: I wasn't sure if Stack Overflow was the right Stack for this. If there's a better one, let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was on [that same Reddit site](https://old.reddit.com/r/FirefoxCSS/comments/11odffm/psa_incoming_changes_to_default_element/). Change `display: -moz-box` to `display: flex`. `display: -moz-box` no longer works.